# Properties of the stochastic integral $\int_0^t\frac{|B_s|}{s}\Bbb dB_s$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals

For a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\geq0}$ we define the process
$$I_t:=\int_0^t\frac{|B_s|}{s}\Bbb dB_s,\qquad (t>0).$$
But what can we say about this process? Is it even possible to define this process? If yes, it is for sure a local martingale, but is it also a (true) martingale? As
$$\Bbb E[I]_t=\Bbb E\int_0^t\frac{B_s^2}{s^2}\Bbb ds=\int_0^t\frac{1}{s}\Bbb ds=\infty,
$$
where $[.]_t$ denotes the quadratic variation, the second moment can't exist if it is a martingale. Also, what can we say about the limit $$I_0:=\lim\limits_{t\searrow0}I_t,$$ does it exist in any sense?
I thought about scaling property, Hölder continuity and the law of the iterated logarithm, but notthing helped. As the limit $$\lim\limits_{t\searrow0}\frac{B_t^2}{t}$$ doesn't exist, I can't just use the Itô formula.

All hints about which properties this process possesses are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$$
I_t = \int_{t}^{2t} \frac{|B_s|}{s} dB_s = \int_1^2 \frac{|B_{tu}|}{tu} dB_{tu}.
$$
By the self-similarity of $B$, $\{B_{tu}, u\in [1,2]\}$ has the same distribution as $\{\sqrt{t}B_{u}, u\in [1,2]\}$. Therefore, $I_t$ has the same law$^*$ as
$$
\int_1^2 \frac{\sqrt{t}|B_{u}|}{tu} \sqrt{t} \,dB_{u} = \int_1^2 \frac{|B_{u}|}{u} dB_{u} = I_1.
$$
On the other hand, if the integral in question were well defined, then we would have $I_t\to 0, t\to0+$, which is impossible (as $I_1$ is not zero a.s.).

---

$^*$ I believe this can be shown in many ways, here's one of the arguments.

Let $B$ be defined canonically, i.e., $\Omega = \{\omega\in C([0,\infty)): \omega(0) = 0\}$, $\mathcal F = \mathcal B(C([0,\infty))$, $\mathrm P$ is the Wiener measure, $B(t,\omega) = \omega(t)$; $\mathcal F_t = \sigma(\{\omega(s) \in A\}, s\in[0,t], A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}$.

The self-similarity means that, for each $C>0$, the transformation $F_C: \omega(\cdot) \mapsto C^{-1/2}\omega(C\cdot)$ preserves $\mathrm P$. Moreover, it agrees with the filtration $(\mathcal F_t,t\ge 0)$ in the sense that $F_C(\mathcal F_t) = \mathcal F_{Ct}, t\ge 0$.

Consider now the Itô integral $I(\xi,B)=\int_0^1 \xi_s dB_s$. It is obtained as a continuous extension (first in $L^2$ for isometric definition, then in probability for extended definition) of integral of simple processes. As a result, $I(\xi,B)(F_C(\omega)) = I\bigl(\xi(F_C(\omega)),B(F_C(\omega))\bigr)$ a.s.: this equality is obvious for simple processes, and then is extended by continuity. On the other hand, since $F_C$ perserves $\mathrm P$, $I(\xi,B)(F_C(\omega))$ and $I(\xi,B)(\omega)$ have the same distribution.

In particular, for $\xi_t = f(t,B_t)$, we have
$$
I(\xi,B)(F_C(\omega)) = \int_0^1 f(s,C^{-1/2}B_{Cs}) C^{-1/2} dB_{Cs}\overset{d}= I(\xi,B) = \int_0^1 f(s,B_{s}) dB_{s}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will denote your integral with $\tilde{I}_t$ in the following to avoid missunderstandings. Just to not missunderstand your answer: The integral $\tilde{I}_t$ in your answer is a well defined process with a stationary distribution. And the point is, if the integral $I_t$ in my question was well definied the limit $I_0$ has to exist almost sure and we could represent $\tilde{I}_t=I_{2t}-I_t$. This leads to the contradiction by taking the limit $t\to0+$. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: I just have still some questions regarding your argumentation. Although I don't know any kind of substitution rule for the time in Itô integrals I think it's not big deal to proof it by using the pathwise definition. But what makes me more curious is the part where you use the fact that for processes which have the same distribution the integral has the same distribution as well. It looks on the first view totally reasonable, but I don't know a theorem which states this. Do you know a book/reference where this is proven?

Comment: @mag, re your first question, yes, this is a perfect understanding of what I wrote. Actually, I would write it this way, but I am a bit superstitious about arguments ad absurdum, so I try to avoid them as much as I can.

Comment: Concerning the second question, I feel that the comment field's too narrow, so I'll complement my answer.